# Why does pip installing a django module update my django version?

Tags: python, django, pip

I am working down a list of module dependencies for a django project I have inherited. I am setting up a local environment on a Windows 7 machine.

One of the first requirements is django==1.4.1, so I am installing this with pip, like this;

```
pip install -U django==1.4.1
```

This works fine. But when I get to some other items, like django-nose, and run

```
pip install -U django-nose==1.1
```

then I notice in the console output that it is updating my copy of django to 1.6.5

I can of course go back and backdate to django==1.4.1 afterwards, but I guess there is a reason for the update, and I'd like to understand it. I want my local environment to match the staging environment I am going to deploy to, is it ok to backdate my version, or is there a way of telling pip not to update django for me? Or is the newer version a requirement of the module I am installing?

Comment: I copied it from the django tutorial. I've just looked it up and see that it means 'Upgrade', what an idiot. Thanks. If you want to answer my q I will accept.

Comment: no worries, you should accept Martijn Pieters answer, there is nothing more I can add to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-U` switch tells `pip` to [upgrade the package *and dependencies*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption-U) to their latest available version:

> `-U`
>   Upgrade all packages to the newest available version. **This process is recursive regardless of whether a dependency is already satisfied.**

Emphasis mine.

`django-nose` depends on `nose` and `Django`, so these are upgraded to their latest versions, you did not explicitly pin them.

Use `--no-deps` if you don't want to upgrade dependencies:

```
pip install -U --no-deps django-nose==1.1
```

or better still, ***don't use `-U`***. You already pinned `django-nose`, so the `-U` switch is ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

The switch `-U` means:
"Upgrade all packages to the newest available version. This process is recursive regardless of whether a dependency is already satisfied."

So you just forced the update yourself.